# click() do not work with <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have an  element and with a function in javascript i want it to "auto click", and it works. But the problem is that the  element has href="#something" and it doesn't change the url.
It should change the hash from `http://url.com` to `http://url.com/#something`

What is wrong?

The code is very simple is something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#something" class="selected">click here</a></li>
<li><a href="#something2">or click here</a></li>
</ul>

//javascript
document.ready(function(){
 $('#menu a').each(function(i){
  if($(this).attr('class') == 'selected'){
   $(this).click();
   $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
  }
 });
});
```

The click() works because color change, but the hash the url stays the same.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can't help you if we can't see the code

Comment: what is this question all about ? your code does something different than you asked

Comment: Ok, i find a very simple way to show the problem: code `<a id="aaa" onClick="$('#ooo').click();">click</a><br><br><a id="ooo" href="#something">click2</a>` So if u click with mouse on ooo hash change, but if u click on aaa it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can add **window.location.hash='something2'** to the code. It will only change the hash value (#something2)

**EDIT**

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#something" rel="something" class="selected">click here</a></li>
<li><a href="#something2" rel="#something2">or click here</a></li>
</ul>


document.ready(function(){
 $('#menu a').click(function(){
  if($(this).attr('class') != 'selected'){
   window.location.hash=$(this).attr('rel');
   $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: ok, but the thing is: if i click with mouse it changes the hash, so why it doesn't change if i do click by javascript?

Comment: You don't need to do the `$(this).click();`. Just replace it with `window.location.hash='something2'`

Comment: I like this solution - thanks Ioana Zlateva I learned something :)

Comment: Ok, i find a very simple way to show the problem: code `<a id="aaa" onClick="$('#ooo').click();">click</a><br><br><a id="ooo" href="#something">click2</a>` So if u click with mouse on ooo hash change, but if u click on aaa it doesn't.

Comment: That's why you do it manually with `window.location.hash=$(this).attr('rel');`

Comment: Ok, but a click should be a click...i think.

Comment: When you click on "aaa" you trigger the onclick function which changes your hash to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

if it looks like this:

```
<a href='#target'>Click me</a>
```

It should work.

Automated:

```
var target = getElementById('linkid').href;
location.replace('url.html#' + target);
```

Comment: That would work if someone clicked it. The OP said **auto**-click, e.g., simulating the event in some way.

Comment: True - I also noticed the javascript tag so I added a javascript solution.

Comment: ok, but the thing is: if i click with mouse it changes the hash, so why it doesn't change if i do click by javascript?

Comment: Do you mean as in element.click ? Cos that works in IE but not Chrome, so I'm guessing click isn't in the standard...?

Comment: Ok, i find a very simple way to show the problem: code `<a id="aaa" onClick="$('#ooo').click();">click</a><br><br><a id="ooo" href="#something">click2</a>` So if u click with mouse on ooo hash change, but if u click on aaa it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the location AND hash you can also do this manually, e.g.

```
document.location = $('#my-link').attr('href');
```

Comment: He is obviously using jQuery in his code example, so I don't see why he would not want to use it to solve this.

Comment: I assumed that because he did mention the "click()" method.

Comment: Ok, i find a very simple way to show the problem: code `<a id="aaa" onClick="$('#ooo').click();">click</a><br><br><a id="ooo" href="#something">click2</a>` So if u click with mouse on ooo hash change, but if u click on aaa it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hugely clear on this one but it's

```
$(this).trigger('click');
```

to trigger the event i.e. force the link to navigate.

```
$(this).click();
```

will just fire the JavaScript event into the DOM. Currently this code won't "autoclick" for that reason

Is that what's required?